# Realtime AudioQueue Record-Playback

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, voice-recording, audioqueue

Hey fellows,
Iam trying to build an application for realtime voicechanging.
In a first step I managed to record audiodata to a specified file and to play it after recording.
Now I try to change the code for playing back the audiobuffers right after recording them in loop.
My question is, how it is possible to read the Audiodata directly from the recording Audioqueue and not (like shown in documentation) from a file.
Iam thankful for any ideas and could show code-parts if needed.
Thanks in advance,
Lukas (from Germany)

Comment: What platform/language are you planning on using? (It's hard to tell from your question.)

Comment: The programm is meant to be working on IPhone. The used language is Objective-C. Up to now most of my code is taken from AudioQueueReference Guide.

Comment: I've re-tagged your question with more meaningful tags - you'll hopefully get more of a response now.

Comment: didn't you refer SpeakHere iOS sample code

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the SpeakHere example. This line sources the audio data:

```
OSStatus result = AudioFileReadPackets(THIS->GetAudioFileID(), false, &numBytes,     inCompleteAQBuffer->mPacketDescriptions, THIS->GetCurrentPacket(), &nPackets, 
                                       inCompleteAQBuffer->mAudioData);
```

So, rather than call `AudioFileReadPackets`, you can just use a memcpy to copy over the recorded data buffer. Or, alternatively, supply to the playback `AudioQueue` a pointer to the audio data buffer. As playback continues, advance a `mCurrentPacket` pointer through the buffer.

To record, you'll do something very similar. Rather than writing out to a file, you'll write out to a buffer in memory. You'll first need to allocate that with a `malloc`. Then are your incoming `AudioQueue` captures recorded data, you copy that data to the buffer. As more data is copied, you advance the recording head, or `mCurrentPacket` to a new position.