# How to provide audio buffer to AudioQueue to play audio?

Tags: iphone, ios4, objective-c++, audioqueue

In my application, I am receiving audio data in LinearPCM format, which I need to play. 
I am following iOS SpeakHere example. However I cannot get how and where I should provide a buffer to `AudioQueue`.

Can anyone provide me a working example of playing audio buffer in iOS via `AudioQueue`?

Answer (score 0):

In the SpeakHere example playback is achieved using `AudioQueue`.

In the set up of `AudioQueue`, a function is specified that will be called when the queue wants more data.

You can see that in this method:

```
void AQPlayer::SetupNewQueue()
```

Here's the line that specifies the callback function:

```
    XThrowIfError(AudioQueueNewOutput(&mDataFormat, AQPlayer::AQBufferCallback, this, 
                                    CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes, 0, &mQueue), "AudioQueueNew failed");
```

If you take a look at `AQPlayer::AQBufferCallback`, you'll see where it gets the data from. In this example, the data has been written out to a file on disk. That's a good solution if you want to save memory, or if there's a possibility the audio file could be quite large.

Anyway, looking at `AQPlayer::AQBufferCallback`, you'll see a call to a function `AudioFileReadPackets`. That's what reads in the audio packets from the file on disk. It reads them straight into the buffer that `AudioQueue` will use:

```
    OSStatus result = AudioFileReadPackets(THIS->GetAudioFileID(), false, &numBytes, inCompleteAQBuffer->mPacketDescriptions, THIS->GetCurrentPacket(), &nPackets, 
                                       inCompleteAQBuffer->mAudioData);
```

That buffer is `inCompleteAQBuffer->mAudioData`.

Finally, the callback function must enqueue the buffer as follows:

```
if (nPackets > 0) {
    inCompleteAQBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize = numBytes;      
    inCompleteAQBuffer->mPacketDescriptionCount = nPackets;     
    AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(inAQ, inCompleteAQBuffer, 0, NULL);
    THIS->mCurrentPacket = (THIS->GetCurrentPacket() + nPackets);
}
```

Note first that it has to check that we have some packets to play. It also has to specify how many bytes are in the buffer.

Then, this line here:

```
THIS->mCurrentPacket = (THIS->GetCurrentPacket() + nPackets);
```

That keeps a track of where we are *overall* in our audio buffer. In other words, as more data is copied in from the file, we need to position the `mCurrentPacket` forward to that the next copy puts data in the correct place.

Comment: @AndaluZ where does the question mention NSData and/or network? Anyway, you are free to offer a better answer.

Comment: MaxLeod you're right, he's not mentioning it. But what he meant, is he **is receiving** audio data like receiving data from a socket and not reading from a file. Copying data to audio buffer based on SpeakHere example project, means getting rid of a lot of File related code that is part of the example. That's what I'm struggling too. As soon as I got it working, I'll drop it here as an answer. I'm sorry for the downvote, I was kind of frustrated.

Comment: the player wants a pointer to a chunk of data in memory. From where that data comes originally - disk or network  - shouldn't matter too much. You can see additional detail in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357514/ios-stream-audio-from-one-ios-device-to-another/8492598#8492598 Also, this answer covers memory playback directly using memcpy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639912/realtime-audioqueue-record-playback/8892971#8892971

Comment: "disk or network - shouldn't matter too much" yes you're right. But in SpeakHere example the copying is done with AudioFileReadPackets() with all kind of extra  parameters for administration like last position of read pointer in a file and so on... which makes it hard to understand as a newbie in this area. But thnx for your help anyway.