# iOS Stream Audio from one iOS Device to Another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, stream

I get a song from the device iTunes library and shove it into an AVAsset:

```
- (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
{
    NSArray *arr = mediaItemCollection.items;

    MPMediaItem *song = [arr objectAtIndex:0];

    NSData *songData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL]];
}
```

Then I have this Game Center method for receiving data:

```
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID
```

I'm having a LOT of trouble figuring out how to send this AVAsset via GameCenter and then have it play on the receiving device.

I've read through:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioStreamReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006162

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW5

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

I am just lost. Information overload.

I've implemented Cocoa With Love's Audio Stream code, but I can't figure out how to take the NSData I receive through GameCenter and shove it into his code.
http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html

Can someone please help me figure this out? So again the part I need help with is simply breaking up song data into packets (or however it works), then iterating through those packets and sending it through gamekit, then parsing that data AS it comes in on the receiving device as PLAY it AS it comes in.

Comment: It should be possible to do what you want. That's what Rogue Amoeba's [Airfoil Speakers](http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/speakers.php) does (except routing is controlled by the sender, not the receiver). But keep in mind that they have worked very hard on this for a long time. Maybe you can piggyback on (or license) their solution.

Comment: What about using GameKit Api? You can send and receive NSData either via BlueTooth or Internet as you like and its not hard to implement at all...
If you have any questions, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The API you need to look at is ["Audio Queue Services"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/audio_queue_services).

Right, here goes for a basic overview of what you need to do.

When you playback audio, you set up a queue or a service. That queue will ask for some audio data. Then, when it has played all that back, it will ask for some more. This goes on until you either stop the queue, or there's no more data to playback.

The two main lower level APIs in iOS are Audio Unit and Audio Queue. By lower level, I mean an API that is a bit more nitty gritty than saying "just play back this mp3" or whatever.

My experience has been that Audio Unit is lower latency, but that Audio Queue is more suited to streaming audio. So, I think for you the latter is a better option.

A key part of what you need to do is buffering. That means loading data sufficiently so that there are no gaps in your playback. You might want to handle this by initially loading a larger amount of data. Then you are playing ahead. You'll have a sufficiently large buffer in memory whilst simultaneously receiving more data on a background thread.

The sample project I would recommend studying closely is [SpeakHere](https://github.com/robovm/apple-ios-samples/tree/master/SpeakHere). In particular look at the classes `SpeakHereController.mm` and `AQPlayer.mm`.

The controller handles things like starting and stopping `AQPlayer`. `AQPlayer` represents an `AudioQueue`. Look closely at `AQPlayer::AQBufferCallback`. That's the callback method that is invoked when the queue wants more data.

You'll need to make sure that the set up of the queue data, and the format of the data you receive matches exactly. Checkout things like number of channels (mono or stereo?), number of frames, integers or floats, and sample rate. If anything doesn't match up, you'll either get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors as you work your way through the respective buffers, or you'll get white noise, or - in the case of wrong sample rates - audio that sounds slowed down or sped up.

Note that SpeakHere runs two audio queues; one for recording, and one for playback. All audio stuff works using buffers of data. So you're always passing round pointers to the buffers. So, for example during playback you will have say a memory buffer that has 20 seconds of audio. Perhaps every second your callback will be invoked by the queue, essentially saying "give me another second's worth of data please". You could think of it as a playback head that moves through your data requesting more information.

Let's look at this in a bit more detail. Differently to SpeakHere, you're going to be working with in memory buffers rather than writing out the audio to a temporary file.

Note that if you're dealing with large amounts of data, on an iOS device, you'll have no choice but to hold the bulk of that on disk. Especially if the user can replay the audio, rewind it, etc., you'll need to hold it all somewhere!

Anyway, assuming that `AQPlayer` will be reading from memory, we'll need to alter it as follows.

First, somewhere to hold the data, in `AQPlayer.h`:

```
void SetAudioBuffer(float *inAudioBuffer) { mMyAudioBuffer = inAudioBuffer; }
```

You already have that data in an `NSData` object, so you can just pass in the pointer returned from a call to `[myData bytes]`.

What provides that data to the audio queue? That's the call back method set up in `AQPlayer`:

```
void AQPlayer::AQBufferCallback(void *                  inUserData,
                            AudioQueueRef           inAQ,
                            AudioQueueBufferRef     inCompleteAQBuffer)
```

The method that we'll use to add part of our data to the audio queue is `AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer`:

```
AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(inAQ, inCompleteAQBuffer, 0, NULL);
```

`inAQ` is the reference to the queue as received by our callback.
`inCompleteAQBuffer` is the pointer to an audio queue buffer.

So how do you get your data - that is the pointer returned by calling the `bytes` method on your NSData object - into the audio queue buffer `inCompleteAQBuffer`?

Using a `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(inCompleteAQBuffer->mAudioData, THIS->mMyAudioBuffer + (THIS->mMyPlayBufferPosition / sizeof(float)), numBytesToCopy);
```

You'll also need to set the buffer size:

```
        inCompleteAQBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize =  numBytesToCopy;
```

`numBytesToCopy` is always going to be the same, *unless* you're just about to run out of data. For example if your buffer is 2 seconds worth of audio data and you have 9 seconds to playback, then for the first four callbacks you will pass 2 second's worth. For the final callback you will only have 1 second's worth of data left. `numBytesToCopy` must reflect that.

```
    // Calculate how many bytes are remaining? It could be less than a normal buffer
    // size. For example, if the buffer size is 0.5 seconds and recording stopped
    // halfway through that. In which case, we copy across only the recorded bytes
    // and we don't enqueue any more buffers.
    SInt64 numRemainingBytes = THIS->mPlayBufferEndPosition - THIS->mPlayBufferPosition;

    SInt64 numBytesToCopy =  numRemainingBytes < THIS->mBufferByteSize ? numRemainingBytes : THIS->mBufferByteSize;
```

Finally, we advance the playback head. In our callback, we've given the queue some data to play. What happens next time we get the callback? We don't want to give the same data again. Not unless you're doing some funky dj loop stuff!

So we advance the head, which is basically just a pointer to our audio buffer. The pointer moves through the buffer like the needle on the record:

```
    SELF->mPlayBufferPosition += numBytesToCopy;
```

That's it! There's some other logic but you can get that from studying the full callback method in SpeakHere.

A couple of points I must emphasis. First, don't just copy and paste my code above. Absolutely make sure you understand what you are doing. Undoubtably you'll hit problems and you'll need to understand what's happening.

Secondly, make sure the audio formats are the same, and even better that you understand the audio format. This is covered in the [Audio Queue Services Programming Guide in Recording Audio](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AQRecord/RecordingAudio.html). Look at *Listing 2-8 Specifying an audio queue’s audio data format*.

It's crucial to understand that you have the most primitive unit of data, either an integer or a float. Mono or stereo you have one or two channels in a frame. That defines how many integers or floats are in that frame. Then you have frames per packet (probably 1). Your sample rate determines how many of those packets you have per second.

It's all covered in the docs. Just make sure everything matches up or you will have some pretty strange sounds!

Good luck!

Comment: nah you don't need to do that. You can have AQPlayer use that data directly. You don't need the intermediate step of writing it out to a file. That said, is it likely you'll need to playback the audio twice?  Or can the user forward or rewind it, etc.?

Comment: ps. let me know and if I can help I'll try to dig out some code for you tomorrow

Comment: I'm having a little trouble following the order of operations here.  Where do I call SetAudioBuffer? To be honest, I'm rather confused overall. So the receiving device gets lets say 10kb of audio data, where do I pass that data to? Then when I want to actually play the audio I call StartQueue? I'm trying really hard here to figure this out, I'm sure i'll get it. I appreciate your patience.

Comment: So is this right: receive my 10kb data, pass it into SetAudioBuffer,then from somewhere call AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(inAQ, inCompleteAQBuffer, 0, NULL) replacing inCompleteAQBuffer with myAudioBuffer, then call StartQueue?

Comment: you're getting there! Don't worry this is tricky stuff, especially when you first see it. It takes time to get the hang of everything. You'll call SetAudioBuffer to set the audio data on your player object. Next, start the queue. That will kick off the callbacks that request the data. In the callback you'll copy some of that data - the data you set in the player with SetAudioBuffer -  to inCompleteAQBuffer->mAudioData with the memcpy. Next, you call AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer.

Comment: So for every chunk of data I will call SetAudioBuffer. But after I call it on the first chunk I will call start queue.  The queue will keep playing the audio so long as I keep passing in data to SetAudioBuffer?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5853/discussion-between-spentak-and-max-macleod)

Comment: Hi sorry I just saw your comments on the chat this morning. Are you still struggling with this? If so, send me an email (on my profile)

Comment: @MaxMacLeod i have my audio queue working.  The problem I have is that im casting my buffers to nsdata then sending them via a socket connection.  but that causes breaks in the audio and clicking noises between buffers.  Any idea how to fix this.  if i append the nsdata buffers the clicking is gone of course, but then audio isnt streaming.  (by the way this is an amazing example!)

Comment: you have to time the buffers to avoid any gaps. Impossible to guarantee that over a network, but you have to do your best. So, transfer a good amount of audio in advance before starting playback. An initial wait of a few seconds is a lot less noticeable than breaks, and pops. Appending buffers shouldn't affect streaming as long as you are sending the correct amount of data.

Comment: The problem I had was that callback wasn't called after AudioQueueStart(mQueue, NULL). After reading your post I realised I had to prime with some data before calling AudioQueueStart(), to let the ball roll. But what's the best solution if I get audio from the network? Call the callback manually or let AudioQueue call the  callback using AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer()? The latter one needs to check if there's something to read, if not call AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer() with size 0.

Comment: Hello @MaxMacLeod can we do this using avaudio engine ? I have a raw audio byte stream coming from ble.

Answer (score 0):

What's your purpose? and How do you call [match sendDataToAllPlayers:...] ? It decides how do you get AVAsset back from data received.

There are steps mentioned:

1. get NSData from mediaPicker for music
2. create AVAsset (are you really doing it?)
3. send to GKPlayers ?
4. recieving NSData from gamecenter
5. get back AVAsset if you are dong 2.
6. use AVPlayer:playerWithPlayItem to get AVPlayer and play

If you are doing some encoding and transmission on your own method, like use AVAssetReader to get raw data and sending, then just do it reversely.