# How to access data in AudioQueue buffers?

Tags: xcode, buffer, real-time, signals, audioqueue

I am struggling to work out how to pass the data from buffer to an array to allow me to display what is in the buffer. Is there an example of code somewhere that is a simple record audio and read buffer? Simpler the better.

I am trying to do something in real time and not read in data from a saved file. I could paste some code that I have tried with no success.

Answer (score 2):

The classic example of writing and reading to audio buffers using `AudioQueue` is Apple's [SpeakHere](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project.

You can find tons of stuff on this and on the web. Just search on "speakhere". One standout page is Matt Gallagher's articles on [Streaming and playing an MP3 stream](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html).

Check out my personal answers also. I have some quite in depth posts on audio buffers, e.g.

[iOS Stream Audio from one iOS Device to Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357514/ios-stream-audio-from-one-ios-device-to-another/8492598#8492598)