# play decoded raw audio data in iPhone

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, audio-streaming, red5

i am developing one streaming application for iOS and i am getting all audio packets correctly and decoded also but now i am totally confused about how to play it on iPhone.. I have decoded packets using ffmpeg.. All codes i get so far are playing audio from a file but i my case i have to play audio packets which i am getting from server in an order they are coming.. I dont want to save all packets to a file so any code that will help me to solve my problem is appreciated..

Thnak you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use Audio Services to do this. Either `AudioQueue` or `AudioUnit`. `AudioQueue` is better for streaming type applications.

The classic sample - for AudioQueue - is [Apple's SpeakHere](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html).

Matt Gallagher also has some superb tutorials with sample code for streaming.

See [Streaming MP3/AAC audio again](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/streaming-mp3aac-audio-again.html).

If you want to go the `AudioUnit` route, see [Using RemoteIO audio unit](http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/).

By basing your code on Matt Gallagher's sample, possibly also using SpeakHere, you should be able to play your decoded packets. See my other answers for how to play using a buffer rather than from a file.

Don't forget that this is quite advanced stuff. You'll need to be comfortable with buffers, pointers, etc. Make sure you understand frames, packets, etc. as well. Some pain in getting your audio out there is to be expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. Actually i have gone through speak here and Matt Gallagher's project but they pretty difficult to understand. Moreover I have found another [link](http://lovingod.host.sk/iphone/developers/audio_queues.html) which I found good but I am confused if I can read file in chunks and then play them.

Comment: it is tricky stuff and that's hard to avoid. You can play the stuff in chunks. You just need to make sure that you have the chunks in advance of playing them. Otherwise you will have a stuttering effect in your audio. If you see my answer here I go into these examples in detail, specifically playback from a buffer rather than a file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357514/ios-stream-audio-from-one-ios-device-to-another/8492598#8492598

Comment: [Max MacLeod]Can I do this using AvPlayer or it is mandatory to use AudioQueue? I just found somewhere so i m curious.. Please help...

Comment: playing from a file you can use AVPlayer. Also I think there is new capability to play from a stream in the media classes. AudioQueue and AudioUnit are lower level where you're handling the raw bytes. Btw feel free to accept the answer or vote up. Would be nice to get some appreciation :-)