# Is there a way to record audio in iOS without using the AVFoundation framework?

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, audio-recording, trigger.io

I am developing native plugins in [trigger.io](http://trigger.io) which does not allow 2 plugins to use the same frameworks in a project.

My audio recorder plugin simply records the audio, saves it and returns the url to the audio file. For this I was using AVAudioSessions and AVAudioRecorder.

I was looking for an alternative method to record the audio through the device's mic without using the usual AVFoundation framework.
Can anyone please suggest an alternative?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357514/ios-stream-audio-from-one-ios-device-to-another/8492598#8492598 Specifically the SpeakHere sample project. Also http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/

Answer (score 4):

Core Audio has several lower level API's. **AudioQueueServices** class is a good place to start and is found in the **AudioToolbox** framework.

For finest grain control **AudioUnits** framework is the closest you can get to the Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL).

These require a lot more code but the reward is worth it. **AVAudioRecorder** is just an objective-c wrapper for some of these lower level frameworks.

For more information look at [Core Audio Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/CoreAudioEssentials/CoreAudioEssentials.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003577-CH10-SW32) documentation. (*look for the section titled Recording and Playback using Audio Queue Services*)

You will still however need the **AVAudioSession** class from the **AVFoundation** framework to manage your applications audio session, as **AudioSessionServices** class is now deprecated.