# How to source headphone jack audio from a buffer rather than an audio file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audioqueue

I am working on an application in which I want to send raw data (text data) to the headphone jack instead of to an audio file. I assume I can do that by using the `AudioQueue` framework. However I don't know how to do that. My app is supposed to function the same way as squareup.com app.

Answer (score 1):

Routing of audio playback depends upon the how you set up your audio session:

```
    UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;  
    error = AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(category), &category);
```

You have five categories to choose from. Once you've chosen a category, then iOS will route the audio signal automatically depending on the hardware. For example you might plug in the headphones and it will stop speaker playback, instead routing the signal to the headphone output.

For the best category to choose, have a look at:[Audio Session Programming Guide - Choosing the Best Category](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html).

Regarding `AudioQueue`, yes that will playback raw audio data in byte format. You start the queue and it will request more data periodically. Have a look at the [SpeakHere](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project. Specifically, have a look at the `AQBufferCallback` in `AQPlayer.mm`.

To source the audio data from a buffer rather a file - which is what I think you mean - have a look at my answers to other questions regarding the SpeakHere sample project:

[Realtime AudioQueue Record-Playback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639912/realtime-audioqueue-record-playback/8892971#8892971)

[How to provide audio buffer to AudioQueue to play audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953925/how-to-provide-audio-buffer-to-audioqueue-to-play-audio/8884405#8884405)